c++ problems with polymorphism and inheritance
I can't get why this code prints
E::n() 
A::m() 
E::j()

if i run
(p4->n()).m();

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
        A() {cout << "A() ";}
        virtual ~A() {cout << "~A() ";}
        virtual const A* j() {cout << "A::j() "; return this;}
        virtual void k() {cout << "A::k() "; m();}
        void m() {cout << "A::m() "; j();}
};

class B: virtual public A{
    public:
        B() {cout << "B() ";}
        virtual ~B() {cout << "~B() ";}
        virtual void g() const{cout << "B::g() ";}
        virtual const B* j() {cout << "B::j() "; n(); return this;}
        void k() {cout << "B::k() "; j(); m();}
        void m() {cout << "B::m() "; g(); j();}
        virtual A& n() {cout << "B::n() "; return *this;}
};

class C: virtual public B{
    public:
        C() {cout << "C() ";}
        ~C() {cout << "~C() ";}
        void g() const{cout << "C::g() ";}
        void k() override{cout << "C::k() "; B::n();}
        virtual void m() {cout << "C::m() "; g(); j();}
        B& n() override{cout << "C::n() "; return *this;}
};

class D: virtual public B{
    public:
        D() {cout << "D() ";}
        ~D() {cout << "~D() ";}
        virtual void g() {cout << "D::g() ";}
        const B* j() {cout << "D::j() "; return this;}
        void k() const {cout << "D::k() "; k();}
        void m() {cout << "D::m() "; g(); j();}
};

class E: public C, public D{
    public:
        E() {cout << "E() ";}
        ~E() {cout << "~E() ";}
        E(const E& x) {cout << "Ec ";}
        virtual void g() const{cout << "E::g() ";}
        const E* j() {cout << "E::j() "; return this;}
        void m() {cout << "E::m() "; g(); j();}
        D& n() final{cout << "E::n() "; return *this;}
};

A* p1 = new E(); B* p2 = new C(); A* p3 = new D(); B* p4 = new E(); 
const A* p5 = new D(); const B* p6 = new E(); const E* p7 = new E();

The focus is on A::m(), why doesn't it print E::n() in its place? The M method is marked as virtual in the C class. Am i missing something?

If you are focused on A::m(), why don't you remove other unrelated part of the code?

i can't touch the code,the exercise is made to answer questions like "what does p2->m() print?", so (p4->n()).m(); is just one of them

This code doesn't print anything.  It has no main.  A [mcve] would be most useful.  Focus on the "minimal" part, by deleting all the irrelevant code.

the main is literally just (p4->n()).m();, i didn't add it because you don't really need to run the code, you can solve it just thinking about how inheritance and polymorphism works in c++. But sure, deleting the irrilevant code helps

 Honestly, I don't get what's the point of such exercises. If anyone sent me code like this to review, I'd immediately reject it and ask the author if this was supposed to be a joke. It doesn't teach you how to deal with real problems, because no real code looks like that. 

I'm guessing that because p4 is a B*, the D& return becomes A& from the return type of B::n(), and then that calls A::m().

Whoever is teaching you C++ is doing a very bad job. (for points mentioned earlier), summary is const correctness is missing. But also code like this A* p1 = new E() should not be used anymore. It should be std::unique_ptr<A> = std::make_unique<E>()

"I can't touch the code" of course you can. As you dont understand it you have to be careful of course. Remove the functions not relevant for the current issue. Do this line by line, after each line compile to see if the output changed, if it did you made a mistake and have to go one step back. While doing that you should also replace the names with proper names. The current ones are maximum confusing. There is really no point in trying to read totally confusing code when you can make it less confusing first.

I think you're being deceived by the covariant return types of n – even if the function is virtual, the return type is determined at compile time from the static type of the object.
p4 is a B*, so p4->n() uses B's interface when calling n.
B::n returns an A&, so (p4->n()).m() uses A's interface when calling m.
A::m is not virtual, so the call does not depend on the runtime type of *p4.

makes perfectly sense, thank you
